# I want to add the spp algorithm to my program so that the input and output images don't have to be fixed

Tags: tensorflow, python-3.6

https://github.com/nickliqian/cnn_captcha
Here is the git address, which is the code I am using.

Hello, I have a verification code recognition program. Now I can model the model and verify the recognition result, but I can only fix the image size of the input and output. Now I want to add the spp(Spatial Pyramid Pooling) algorithm into my program. I have tried many times and can't solve it normally. Can you help me? Thank you.

https://github.com/nickliqian/cnn_captcha

Let the input and output pictures not be in fixed size